# ASP.NET MVC 4 trying to load data into drop downlist from xml file

Tags: xml, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to load a xml file into dropdownlist in ASP.NET MVC.

In the `layout.cshtml` I have the dropdwnlist like this

```
@Html.DropDownList("Market", ViewBag.Market as SelectList,  new { id = "Market" })
```

In the controller I read from the xml file and assign like this:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    DataSet marketDS = new DataSet();
    marketDS.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Content//XmlData/Markets.xml"));

    EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> DV1 = marketDS.Tables["Market"].AsEnumerable();

    ViewBag.Market= new SelectList(DV1.ToList<DataRow>(), "ID", "Value");
    return View();
}
```

I get this error:

> DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with
>   the name 'ID'.

But I can see in the DV1 it has read from the xml file and contains ITEM Array with all the items from the xml file.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC and don't know what I am doing... It used to pretty easy with webforms to bind data to dropdown list in the .cs file. Here its pretty confusing. Any help?

I worked it out like this

//Loads values for the DropDownList Market
            DataSet marketDS = new DataSet();
            marketDS.ReadXml(Server.MapPath("~/Content//XmlData/Markets.xml"));

```
        EnumerableRowCollection<DataRow> DR1 = marketDS.Tables["Market"].AsEnumerable();

        List<string> marketList=new List<string>();
        foreach (DataRow dr in DR1)
        {
            marketList.Add(dr.ItemArray[1].ToString());
        }
        ViewBag.Market = new SelectList(marketList.AsEnumerable().ToList());
```

Answer (score 0):

I would take a slightly different approach here, and use the `DropDownListFor` HTML helper instead.

In your **ViewModel** :

```
public SelectList Items { get; set; }
```

In your **Controller** :

```
var model = new YourViewModel();
model.Items = new SelectList(DV1.ToList<DataRow>(), "ID", "Value");
return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml", model);
```

On your **Webpage** :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Items, Model.Items)
```

Comment: May be @Html.DropDownList(m=>m.Market, Model.Items)

Comment: thanks for ur answers I worked it out as above ,don't the whether its the best way to do it ,but works :-)

Comment: @Lav, it is OK what you did... but is better using models instead of the ViewBag... the compiler will detect errors instead of change something and realize on runtime... and you are using the "M" of MVC :)